# Get property value of a complex type with reflection in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reflection

I have an object like this

```
oldEntity
     Active: true
    ActiveDirectoryName: ""
    ArchiveConceptValueList: null
    AsgScndCnpRangeDictionary: Count = 0
    AssignedRuleList: {NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag<GTS.Clock.Model.AssignedRule>}
    AssignedScndCnpRangeList: {NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag<GTS.Clock.Model.AssignedScndCnpRange>}
    AssignedScndCnpRangePeresentList: {NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag<GTS.Clock.Model.AssignedScndCnpRange>}
    AssignedWGDShiftList: {NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag<GTS.Clock.Model.AssignedWGDShift>}
    AssignedWorkGroupList: {GTS.Clock.Model.PersonWorkGroup, GTS.Clock.Model.PersonWorkGroup}
    Assistant: null
    BarCode: "0451343786"
    BasicTrafficController: {GTS.Clock.Model.Concepts.BasicTrafficController}
    BasicTrafficList: {}
    BudgetList: null
    CFPNeedUpdate: false
    CalcDateZone: null
    CardNum: "2465"
    CartOrgan: {GTS.Clock.Model.Charts.Department}
    CheckEnterAndExitInRequest: false
    CostCenter: {GTS.Clock.Model.BaseInformation.CostCenter}
    CurrentActiveContract: null
    CurrentActiveDateRangeGroup: null
    CurrentActiveRuleGroup: null
    CurrentActiveWorkGroup: null
    CurrentRangeAssignment: null
    CurrentYearBudgetList: {NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag<GTS.Clock.Model.Concepts.CurrentYearBudget>}
    DelayCartableList: {}
    Department: {GTS.Clock.Model.Charts.Department}
    DepartmentID: 0
    ...
```

And I want the name fiel of Department.
Besides Department in oldEntity like this:
[image]
and properies of Department field like this:
[image]

once I use below code to get name field of Department with Reflection ,I got this erro

```
oldEntity.GetType().GetProperty("Department").GetValue("Name", null);
```

> Object does not match target type.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to get the value of a property as if it were a property of `string` - the first argument to `GetValue` needs to be the object you're fetching the property from (`oldEntity` in this case). So you can get the department like this:

```cs
object department = oldEntity.GetType().GetProperty("Department").GetValue(oldEntity, null);
```

To get the `Name` property (which I *hope* is a property and not a public field) you need to do the same kind of thing again:

```cs
object name = department.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(department, null);
```

However, you could do this all somewhat more simply using dynamic typing:

```cs
dynamic entity = oldEntity;
string name = entity.Department.Name;
```

Note that there's no compile-time checking for the `Department` or `Name` parts (or that the resulting type is `string`) but that's the same as for the reflection-based code anyway. The dynamic typing would just do the reflection for you at execution time.

Comment: you are righ,thanks